# tcl from c# package require err

Tags: c#, package, tcl, require

I'm running the following c# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace TCLRunner
{
    class Program
    {
        private static TclInterpreter interp;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                        interp = new TclInterpreter();
                        //interp.evalScript(@"cd ..");
                        interp.evalScript(@"set a ""this is a""");
                        interp.evalScript(@"puts ""Free text""");
                        interp.evalScript(@"puts $a");
                        interp.evalScript(@"package require Tcl");
                        printResults();
                        interp.evalScript(@"package require http");
                        printResults();
                        //
                        // 

                        // Shutdown and end connection



                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
                }
        }
        public static void printResults()
        {
            string result = interp.Result;
            Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", result);
        }

    }

public class TclAPI
    {

        [DllImport("tcl84.DLL")]
        public static extern IntPtr Tcl_CreateInterp();
        [DllImport("tcl84.Dll")]
        public static extern int Tcl_Eval(IntPtr interp, string skript);
        [DllImport("tcl84.Dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr Tcl_GetObjResult(IntPtr interp);
        [DllImport("tcl84.Dll")]
        unsafe public static extern char* Tcl_GetStringFromObj(IntPtr tclObj, IntPtr length);
    }
public class TclInterpreter
    {
        private IntPtr interp;
        public TclInterpreter()
        {
            interp = TclAPI.Tcl_CreateInterp();
            if (interp == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new SystemException("can not initialize Tcl interpreter");
            }
        }
        public int evalScript(string script)
        {
            return TclAPI.Tcl_Eval(interp, script);
        }
        unsafe public string Result
        {
            get
            {
                IntPtr obj = TclAPI.Tcl_GetObjResult(interp);
                if (obj == IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    return "";
                }
                else
                {
                    return Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi((IntPtr)TclAPI.Tcl_GetStringFromObj(obj, IntPtr.Zero));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

Free text
this is a
Received: 8.4
Received: can't find package http

How comes it doesn't find http package?

When I try the same thing manually on tclsh, it works with no problems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the library before calling `Tcl_CreateInterp()`. The library is initialized by calling `Tcl_FindExecutable` with the name of the binary running things as known, but that can be left as `NULL` relatively safely; it's the *other* things that (poorly-named) function does that matter, such as setting up where to find its libraries.

The correct declaration in C# is this (though that `MarshalAs` attribute is optional in this case):

```
[DllImport("tcl84.DLL")]
public static extern void Tcl_FindExecutable([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string s);
```

And you invoke it like this, *exactly once*:

```
TclAPI.Tcl_FindExecutable(null);
```

(It's probably wisest to do so as part of a static constructor in the `TclAPI` class. Yes, it belongs *that* early.)

---

If that doesn't work (I really can't test!) you'll have to [set up some environment variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The key one will be [`TCL_LIBRARY`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/tclvars.htm#M7) which overrides the default location Tcl looks for its support scripts (including the `http` package), and you might need to set `TCLLIBPATH` as well. (Note that `TCL_LIBRARY` is there mainly to support pre-installation testing, but has a history of being set at the system level by <s>Python</s> other systems that ought not to. *Beware!*)

Again, this must be done prior to the `Tcl_CreateInterp()` call.